# Netsuite: SuiteCommerce Advanced Local Development

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

DO you have to have a CNAME and hosting to work on SCA locally? It appears so, I could be wrong, Im just wondering if there is any way to get around this using alternate hosting methods like Azure App Services or CDN's

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add any domain you want in NetSuite. As long as your hosts file points to it, along with the NetSuite IP, you'll be able to access it via that domain.

You don't need to purchase a domain to access it, provided it's a host file entry :)